# How can we have an Association that is not an Aggregation?

Tags: oop, uml, aggregation

Aggregation is defined as a special case of association. However, any association that is not implemented as a field (like having a relationship through method parameters) are being described as "use" relationship.

So, is it possible to have an association that is not aggregation or composition? If yes, I need a code example for such a case, please.

Comment: An interesting question. +1 and welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shared aggregation (empty diamond) is not defined strictly in the UML standard. So, it is not easy to find a situation, where you can not use it.

But it is explicitely forbidden to use it for both sides of association. So, if you have relation many to many, you have to show it on class diagram as many to many association with `none` aggregation. Of course, you can show it as TWO shared association, but it is not our target, is it? :-)

As for code, if people visit many courses and courses are visited by many people, make a list "courses" for Person class and a list "visitors" for Course class.

Of course, on the other side, you always can use `none` instead of `shared` for any `shared` association, it is at your wish and up to rules of your place of work. But I don't know these rules, sorry :-). But surely, nobody will make you to use aggregation for 1 to 1 association.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, I'd say that most cases of associations in models are neither aggregations nor compositions (both are forms of part-whole relationship types). For instance, the association between the classes `Publisher`and `Book` for assigning the books published by a publisher to this publisher is neither an aggregation nor a composition because the books published by a publisher are not parts or components of this publisher.

[image: A model of the association between Publisher and Book]

For implementing this bidirectional association, we use the two mutually inverse reference properties `Publisher::publishedBooks` and `Book::publisher`, as shown in the following class rectangles:

[image: An association-free class model]

Notice that the multi-valued reference property `Publisher::publishedBooks` is normally implemented by a list-valued property in Java.

I have explained how to use associations and reference properties in design models in my tutorial [Managing Unidirectional Associations in a JavaScript Frontend Web App](https://web-engineering.info/tech/JsFrontendApp/unidirectional-association-tutorial.html).

Comment: Are you sure that publisher-book association cannot be shown as aggregated one? Nobody spoke about composition.

Comment: Due to its lack of meaning, it is not recommended to use the UML concept of "aggregation" in software design models. And in terms of the example's domain semantics, there is no sense of parthood under which we can view a book as a part of its publisher.

Comment: Obviously, the composition is out of question. But where have you taken from that "it is not recommended..."? Please, not recommended by whom? Is there some absolute central authority for SW development? And beware, such arguments, as "it is well known that..." are informal fallacies (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentum_ad_populum) and are forbidden in honest discussion. I hope, you used it by error.